# Agent Pool Windows Service

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, build-automation, build-agent

I have already created the ***TFS Build Agent pool windows service*** that is running periodically and tries to connect to **TFS**,
It seems it tries to run with its own credentials and the windows service is installed on a Server that is not in the same domain as TFS (but I can access the TFS from this sever), so It fails with the below error
Error in the service log file:

---

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException:
>   VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://tfsURL.
>
> ---

How to impersonate or making the agent Pool Windows service connected as "NT AUTHORITY\Network" or with another credentials from **server** in a domain to the **TFS** which in another domain

Answer (score 0):

You can either re-configure the build agent to enter a name of the user account to use for the service like the screenshot below:

[image]

Or open the Services, right click the agent service, and then select Log On tab to change the account that runs the agent:

[image]